# Easy way to detect whether rspec or cucumber is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber

I'm currently checking in some places whether code is being executed in test mode, by

```
Rails.env.test?
```

I would like to go one step further, and check whether it is Cucumber or Rspec executing the code, in order to finetune some methods for i18n (which I do want to run differently in a Cucumber context, but not in an Rspec context)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `RAILS_ENV=cucumber` and then [ask](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/env/class#809-Pretty-way-to-test-for-current-environment):

```
Rails.env.cucumber?
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `cucumber-rails` gem, and with that at least you can do `defined?(Cucumber)`. That will return `"constant"` if you're running a cuke or `nil` if you're running a spec.