# How to Detect if Ruby is Running a Cucumber Test

Tags: ruby, cucumber, environment-variables

Very similar to this question: [Easy way to detect whether rspec or cucumber is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193573/easy-way-to-detect-whether-rspec-or-cucumber-is-running)

How can I detect in Ruby that I am running under cucumber?

I have some path variables in a common code project that will need to be changed if the code being used is a cucumber project or a standard script. I'm trying to cover a relative pathing issue. require_relative '../../{filename}' will fail when the file structure is different when under the cucumber structure. It would need to traverse back two more levels like: '../../../../{filename}'.

Common Project: C:\RubyProjects\common-project\common

- build_properties.rb

  ```
  def build_properties_from_yaml('', '')
    params = YAML.load_file(File.absolute_path << '/utils/parameters.yml')
  end
  ```

Cucumber Project: C:\RubyProjects\programs\2017\features\step_definitions

- test_rest.rb

  ```
  require_relative './../../../RubyProjects/common-project/common'

  class Verify

    include Common

    build_properties_from_yaml('', '')
  end
  ```

Some Other Project: C:\RubyProjects\programs\2017\

- File.rb

  ```
  require_relative './../../RubyProjects/common-project/common'

  class RunCode

    include Common

    build_properties_from_yaml('', '')
  end
  ```

With the case of the "utils" folder, it sits under the features folder in cucumber but there is no such folder in other projects without cucumber. That is what throws off the code and i'd like to check for cucumber in the yaml load process.

Comment: Can you please explain why your code need to know if it is running in a test environment? And how you want to change the behavior of your code, because I would consider it a code smell if your code needs to know if it runs in test or another context. Why test code if the code works differently in tests than in other environments? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: You are probably correct, it's most likely a bad coding practice on my part. An issue I am trying to resolve is including common code from one project into multiple other projects. cucumber has a specific file structure that i am attempting to have the code be aware of and load in files relatively correctly.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but why does the relative path from the source file to the file that you want to require change when running in test env? Do you want to require a different file? Would you mind to add a simplified example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: @spickermann, I attempted to add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just `if Rails.env.test?` does not work for you, you may add to the `features/support/env.rb`:

```
ENV['CUCUMBER'] = "true"
```

Then examine it where you want:

```
if ENV['CUCUMBER']
  ...
end
```

You can wrap this in a method somewhere and use it.

**EDIT:** @spikermann's comments are absolutely right. For sure, you're doing something wrong if your code depends from an env. But in some cases (one-time code or  kind of) it could be easier to make a hack.

Comment: I get this error: no implicit conversion of true into String (TypeError) for ENV['CUCUMBER'] = true

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. I've edited the answer. Just make a "true" string.